# Passing a variable into <include> 's layout tag

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, android-databinding

Hello I want to create a base xml that can hold variable layouts in itself. This is the basic idea:

Base Layout:

```
<data>
    <variable name="view" type="android.support.annotation.DrawableRes">
    <variable name="viewModel" type="myBaseViewModel">
</data>

<RelativeLayout> 

    <include layout="@{view}"
        bind:viewModel=@{viewModel}>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item Layout:

```
<layout> 
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="myBaseViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <TextView text = "@{viewModel.myText}" />
</layout>
```

Binder Layout:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="myViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <include layout="@layout/myBaseLayout"
        bind:view="@layout/myItemLayout"
        bind:viewModel="@{viewModel}/>
</layout>
```

Is there any way that can be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you also would like this field to be updated along with variable. No, this is not possible.
You have to get this field reference in background and update it every time you update variable.

Comment: Actually no, I want to make it declared only once. I just want to improve code reusability and trying ways to achieve that.

Comment: still answer is not. If you know value and it is always the same, you can put it manually into layout, but if you want it to have value of varaible you must do it manually.